# How to integrate a third party library to Android in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, stanford-nlp, buildpath

I am trying to integrate Stanford POS tagger to my android application by following the tutorial at :http://new.galalaly.me/2011/05/tagging-text-with-stanford-pos-tagger-in-java-applications/

These are the steps that I followed,

1. I created a new folder called taggers and saved .taggers and .props file in there
2. I imported the library to my project by right clicking my project>Configure Build Path>Add External Jars
3. Then I wrote my code,

   ```
   package cct.mad.numbers;
   import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.widget.TextView;
   public class sum2 extends Activity{

   MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");   
   private TextView text;
   String sample = "This is a sample text";


   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.text2);

   text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.news);
   // The tagged string
   String tagged = tagger.tagString(sample);

   text.setText(tagged);
   }

   }
   ```

However, it gives an error on

```
    MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger("taggers/left3words-wsj-0-18.tagger");
```

saying: "Default constructor cannot handle exception type ClassNotFoundException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor"

Also when I hover over, MaxentTagger in the above code and

```
  import edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger;
```

it says: "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found"

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please first copy the library project into the workspace than try to add the external jar...

Comment: I don't know how to do that. That is my problem

Comment: for this first you need to import the library project in your workspace click on file their is the option of import select the existing android code and tick the checkbox copy the project into workspace and click ok . ... then try to set the library property of your project....

Comment: it is not possible to do this because "Stanford POS tagger" is not android code.

Comment: I even tried to save the file in assets folder and build a path into the assets folder but it still doesn't work